# Am I creating my android app properly? Will it affect performance in any way?

Tags: android, performance, android-activity

So basically my app works like this. There's a list of Physics equations to choose from. Each equation (i.e: Vf = Vi+at) has it's own entire activity (uses both xml and java). Here's an example of how an activity looks like for an equation:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/4i4eH.jpg)

So let's say that I want to create 100 equations for my app. **Would I have to create 100 separate activities as well?**

-**If yes**, then would it affect performance, and by how much would the size of the apk file increase? Is there a simple way to categorize the activities into directories?
-**If no**, then how would I combine those "100 separate activities" into fewer activities?

So far I have only done 3 equations and I have created a separate activity for each. Here is how the selection page looks like.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/z75c5.jpg)

**Example:**
If I select the "Solve for Final Velocity" option from the spinner, it will do the following command  and opens up the activity for the selected equation.

```
//What happens when user chooses a category
 if(position == 1){
 startActivity(vf);
```

Comment: You are welcome to have 100 **layouts**, definitely not 100 **activities**

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your approach. No performance issues, no huge apk sizes, no down sides. Aside from having to navigate 100 layout files of course.

Comment: You could try to group them by the required input/output values. If you have 3 equations with 2 input values and 1 result and 5 equations with 3 input values and 1 result you would only need 2 activities. But in your case its probably better to construct the UI in code without touching any layout xml file. That way you can create dynamically as many TextViews or EditText as you need. You *just* need a model that describes the equation with the required inputs/outputs and their names.

Comment: Couldn't you create an array list of equation objects which hold the title, amount of inputs, input descriptions, and calculation.  Then you update the UI programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of calling multiple Activities, try using the same Activity and Manipulate the views and its contents accordingly.

**Example**

If user selects the "Solve for Final Velocity" option from the spinner, it will do the following.

```
Intent i;

if(position == 1){ 
 i = new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);
 i.putExtra("Action","Equation1");
 startActivity(i);
}else{
 i = new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);
 i.putExtra("Action","Equation2");
 startActivity(i);
}
...
```

In your SecondActivity.java

```
String input1,input2, formula;

String Action = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Action");
//now you have "What to do solved"

switch(Action){
  case "Equation1" :
      //manipulate your formula for Equation1
  break;
  case "Equation2" : 
     //manipulate your formula for Equation2
  break;
}
```

You can even hide particular Views if you don't need them for a particular Equation.

Hope this helps.

Comment: What about the xml layouts?
Like, some equations require 3 EditText fields, some need 4 fields.
Would I still require multiple xml layouts, that is, separate xml layouts for each equation?

Comment: make only one xml layout with the maximum amount of EditTexts required. For Example if the maximum EditText Required are 4, have 4 EditText in the layout and then when a particular Equation needs only 2 EditText hide the other 2. and Change your Titles in TextViews respectively.